# Pause and Resume downloading a file in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, node-fetch

This is a stripped version of a file download module.
It's an Electron app with React on the front-end, so all Node related things work.

Besides the below code, i'm using `res.body.destroy()` to close the download at any point.
Also using `node-fetch` to manage the download process.

**I'm looking for a way to Pause and Resume the download.**

Any example or link would be really apreciated.
Thanks!

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
import fs from 'fs';

let receivedBytes = 0;
let onEachProgress = 0;

const res = await fetch(url);

const totalBytes = res.headers.get('content-length');

const fileStream = fs.createWriteStream(`....zip`);

(downloadStart(fileId));

res.body.pipe(fileStream);

res.body.on('data', chunk => {
  const percentage = Math.round((receivedBytes * 100) / totalBytes);
  receivedBytes += chunk.length;
  onEachProgress += 1;

  downloadProgress(res);
});

res.body.on('end', () => {
  dispatch(downloadEnd());
});
```